# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Android Studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

[image][image]`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`I created a sample project and shared the debug .apk file via google drive and tried to install it crashed. I could install the application from USB without a problem. I am getting following. I posted my gradle file. not sure what's going on

```
05-22 11:54:57.363 22469-22469/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: chin.demo.app.com.nm, PID: 22469
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{chin.demo.app.com.nm/chin.demo.app.com.nm.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "chin.demo.app.com.nm.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/chin.demo.app.com.nm-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/chin.demo.app.com.nm-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "chin.demo.app.com.nm.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/chin.demo.app.com.nm-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/chin.demo.app.com.nm-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: chin.demo.app.com.nm.MainActivity
                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                        ... 12 more
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available




apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "chin.demo.app.com.nm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

`

Comment: Add your manifest file

Comment: yooo @MikeM gotcha mate.. do you know anything ? or just a formatter ?

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda have you tried my answer

Comment: the class name `"chin.demo.app.com.nm.MainActivity"` looks suspicious, do you really have such activity?

Comment: @ArpitPatel yeah mate I tried it but no luck :-(

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda : Can you post a screenshot of your packageStructure along with your full Manifest file

Comment: Check these different methods one of them work

Comment: @TerrilThomas added mate

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda : Full Manifest file also.. You have just posted below the Application Tag

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya tried it  mate issue still the same

Comment: @pskink Yeah mate you can refer my screens

Comment: this is just a sample project I generated from android studio even this one can not share and install from google drive

Comment: @TerrilThomas snap added mate sorry my bd

Comment: try this command in your CMD/Terminal to build apk : gradlew assembleDebug

It will give you an error if something is wrong or it will make a perfect runnable apk. Let me know if still it crashes after you do this

Comment: @TerrilThomas Thanks mate you save my day !!!!! cheers dude hat's off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command in your CMD/Terminal to build apk : **gradlew assembleDebug**

Comment: @ChinthakaDevinda : Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Generate apk file using **AndroidStudio**

> BUILD -> Build APK

**OR**

```
// Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
```

**OR**

1. Right click on your project and select **Properties**.
2. Select **Java Build Path** from the menu on the left.
3. Select the **Order and Export** tab.
4. From the list make sure the libraries or external jars you added to your project are *checked*.
5. Finally, clean your project & run.

Hope it works.

Comment: Just build apk.

Comment: bro I am not using eclipse I am using Android studio